# Transaction pending on Ropsten

Tags: remix, contract-invocation, metamask, ropsten

I deployed a contract on JavaScript VM using remix online IDE.  Here is the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract FileDetail {
 struct File{
    string fileName;
    string fileHash;
 }

 File[] private files;

 function setFile(string fName, string fileHash) public{
 File memory file = File({fileName:fName,fileHash:fileHash});
  files.push(file);
 }

 function getFile(uint256 index) external view returns(
 string fileName,
 string fileHash

 ){

   File memory file = files[index];
   fileName = file.fileName;
   fileHash = file.fileHash;

 }
}
```

On JavaScript VM the contract gets deployed and the set and get methods works fine. But when I try to deploy the same contract, it first opens metamask and after clicking submit it says:

```
creation of FileDetail pending

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x66a2c43405387e9df8d7f406e7b0d755b55930faf4f3da9d92621a2bbe31417e
```

Its been an hour. I also unlocked the account using eth on localhost. My ropsten node logs shows the following:

```
INFO [08-01|14:15:33.141] Submitted contract creation fullhash=0x66a2c43405387e9df8d7f406e7b0d755b55930faf4f3da9d92621a2bbe31417e contract=0x157d49aA855bf99f025f9f9eF8B45Be9a237bD5B
```

Comment: Is your ropsten node fully synced? Nodes will not broadcast transactions if they are too far behind.

Comment: Yes. eth.syncing returns false.

Comment: What is your latest block number? Do you have any peers? Can't broadcast if there are no peers.

Comment: eth.blockNumber says 3750169. How to check peers ?

Comment: `net.peerCount`

Comment: net.peerCount returns 4

Comment: Well, doesn't seem to have been broadcasted. Try getting the raw tx from the node, and pushing it via etherscan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80979/discussion-between-vivek-sadh-and-raghav-sood).

Comment: Replied on chat.